# How to retrieve the prediction matrix according to the formula of a regression model in R?

Tags: r, regression

Suppose I have a logistic regression model such like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(
y=rbinom(100,1,0.5),
x1=rnorm(100,10,2),
x2=rbinom(100,20,0.6))

fit<-glm(y~x1*x2,data=df,family="binomial")
coef(summary(fit))
               Estimate Std. Error    z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  5.08314564 6.43692399  0.7896855 0.4297115
x1          -0.66691041 0.64071095 -1.0408912 0.2979260
x2          -0.28338654 0.51254819 -0.5528974 0.5803337
x1:x2        0.04037126 0.05100223  0.7915588 0.4286180
```

Does somebody know how to get the prediction matrix in a format like this:

```
    intercept x1       x2  x1:x2
1   1        10.506637 10  105.06637
2   1        9.942906  17  169.02941
3   1        9.914259  10  99.14259
4   1        12.737205 11  140.10925
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `model.matrix()`:

```
model.matrix(fit)
```